# How to start the gunicorn service without sudo

Tags: ubuntu, gunicorn, user-permissions

I usually do a `sudo service gunicorn start` to start the gunicorn service, so my app whenever needs to create a folder the ownership belongs to the user logged in when ran the command and the group belongs to sudo. My question is, why when I try to call the service as `service gunicorn start` I get the error

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.20" (uid=1001 pid=10684 comm="start gunicorn ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init ")
```

I know that it has to do with permissions but I can not fully understand what this message mean and how I can call the service without `sudo`. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Linux services must be started by root, unless you use sudo. For instance, if you check your scripts services:

```
lgallard@host:~$ ls -l /etc/init.d/* | head
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2243 abr  3  2014 /etc/init.d/acpid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2014 feb 19  2014 /etc/init.d/anacron
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9974 ene  7  2014 /etc/init.d/apache2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4596 mar 27  2014 /etc/init.d/apparmor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2801 oct 30  2014 /etc/init.d/apport
```

You will realize all belongs to root.

On the other hand, you can check if gunicorn has a flag to run the process as a daemon, and check if it can run with a predefined user. But I guess the best way is by using Linux services, so you can enable or disable them at startup using tools like sysv-rc-conf or chkconfig.

Best regards!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.I will need some time to study it and understand it.Now in order to elaborate more I would have to confess that my optimal goal is not to start the service as non sudo,but to debug the following issue:On my dev server, when I am logged in as user "user1" and start PyCharm with sudo and run my application a folder is created with `ownership:group` = `user1:sudo`, whereas when I start PyCharm as non sudo the same folder is created as `user1:user1`.So I wanted to verify that the same holds in the production server (that the gunicorn runs). Thank you again!

Comment: I even tried to remove group `sudo` from the user but the folder is created as `user1:sudo` and not as `user1:user1` which is the desired and I was hoping to accomplish by running gunicorn as a non sudo.